# Question regarding install/update packages through conda install

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, spyder

My question is:

suppose I have two environment, base and a virtual environment named venv

If I install/update a package in the base environment through

```
conda install package
```

will the package inside the venv also be updated?

And if I update the venv'package, will the package under base environment be updated?

if so, how could I prevent them update together(I want to update/install in one environment and keep the other environment clean)

As for why I ask this question is that I noticed some packages updated in base environment silently(I didn't update,I always update/install in venv environment)and If I incidentally corrupt my venv envrionment(say,update some package improperly,which is very often); I can still recover from the healthy,clean base environment.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the virtual environment (venv) was installed with [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io) inside of the base conda environment.

Installing or updating packages inside of venv should have no effect on the base environment.

The other way around (assuming you update packages with conda while out of venv), it depends:

- If venv was created with a recent version of virtualenv or with the `--no-site-packages` flag (deprecated because now [the default](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/#virtualenv-command)), packages updates out of venv should have no impact.
- If venv was created with a recent version of virtualenv or with the `--system-site-packages` flag, then yes packages updates out of venv should have an impact.

Last option, updating packages with conda while inside of the virtual environment is asking for trouble.

Since you are using conda, why not make two conda environments and stop using virtualenv? Also, since you put the pip tag, I recommand having a look at [Using Pip in a Conda Environment](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment) to understand the pip/conda interaction.

Comment: It is good idea to create another environment isolated to prevent inter corruption; you are right, there is indeed unknown effect when I put virtual environment under the base folder